# Run DTEXEC from SSMS to run SSIS Catalog Package

Tags: ssis, ssms-2017, dtexec

I would like to execute SSIS package using Catalog in a stored procedure using DTEXEC:

> DECLARE @cmd varchar(8000)
> DECLARE @params varchar(4000)
> SELECT @params = '/SET
> \Package.Variables[User::VarBigInt].Properties[Value];"' +
> CONVERT(char(10), @VarBigInt) + '" '     SELECT @params = @params +
> '/SET \Package.Variables[User::VarDate].Properties[Value];"' +
> CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20), @VarDate,101) + ' " '
>
> SELECT @params = @params + '/SET
> \Package.Variables[User::VarDestination].Properties[Value];"' +
> @VarDestination+ '" '
> SELECT @params = @params + '/SET
> \Package.Variables[User::VarBoolean].Properties[Value];"' +
> CONVERT(CHAR(1), @VarBoolean) + '" '      SELECT @params = @params +
> '/SET \Package.Variables[User::VarString].Properties[Value];"' +
> @VarString+ '" '            SELECT @params = @params + '/SET
> \Package.Variables[User::VarList].Properties[Value];"' + @VarList+ '"
> '
>
> SELECT @cmd = 'dtexec ' +N'/ISSERVER ""\SSISDB\test\test'+
> @PackageName +'" /SERVER ""'+ @DestServerName +'"" /ENVREFERENCE 1
> ' + @params + '"$ServerOption::SYNCHRONIZED(Boolean)";True'

This is failing at

> SELECT @params = @params + '/SET
> \Package.Variables[User::VarDate].Properties[Value]";' +
> CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20), @VarDate,101) + '''"'

upon running the stored procedure to deploy this to catalog:
Option " /SET \Package.Variables[User::VarDate].Properties[Value];01/15/2019" is not valid.

VarDate is a datetime variable in the SSIS package.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some **"** around both sets of `SET`

`SELECT @params = @params + '/SET "\Package.Variables[User::VarDate].Properties[Value]";"' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20), @VarDate,101) + '"'`